# Exception when trying to create a trigger using SQLQuery

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, triggers

I have a SQL in my `sqlStr` like this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_T 
AFTER INSERT ON TEST 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO TEST_LOG VALUES(NEW.ID, 3);
END $$
```

And I use this string like this, to have my triggered created while running my application:

```
Transaction t = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlPart);
query.executeUpdate();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
t.commit();
```

But I receive an exception which says:

```
WARN  2013-04-24 16:12:48,238 [main] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
ERROR 2013-04-24 16:12:48,239 [main] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_T 
AFTER INSERT ON TEST' at line 1
```

Note that this `sqlStr` content is just fine when executed in MySQL separately. But here it cannot be executed. Why?

Comment: Do you need to define a DELIMITER ?Can you add `DELIMITER ;` at the end and check?

Comment: can you post the structure of test_log ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained I did just as I create my triggers normally. Do I need `DELIMITER` here? It is all the sql part I need to have, and nothing more. So you tell me, can I remove the delimiter part?

Comment: @IanKenney this table has two `COLUMNS`, both `BIG INTEGER`. No big deal.